# UITextfield editing changed event handle issue

Tags: ios5, uitextfield, iphone-sdk-4.1, uitextfielddelegate

I want to call the web api when uitextfield text changed.problem is,if i type text fast ex "abcd" it call the api four times.I want to handle the api call,if i type fast then is should call the api one time with hole string.If i type slowly then its ok.normally we type fast then  it call the api many times its a problem.

any one have idea for this

```
- (IBAction)editTextField:(id)sender {

         [self callapiwithtype_text];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating an Operation Queue that only allows a single operation to execute at a time.  When your action fires, have it cancel any executing operations, and create and execute a new operation.  This way only the "last" operation will be active, and only the final request will return results.

Another option is to add a delay between the time the event fires and you call the API.  If another event is received before the delay is up, don't send the request.